# Think this is a naming problem

Tags: jquery

Must be really dumb today - sorry in advance; anyhow have this unordered list

```
<ul>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Info</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Appearence</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Pages</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Services</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Community</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
</ul>
```

which on click `<div class="openuserform" >` I want to load a separate form e.g.

```
$('.openusersform').live('click',(function(){ 
$('.userform').load('form page.php'); 
});
```

OK I can get the forms to load in the right div using

```
$(this).next('.userform').show();
$('.userform').load('form page.php');
```

but it's very ugly (I think) and I can only every get the first form to process properly.

It is laid out like (`ul`, `li` etc.) this so I can have each loaded form aligned under the relevant `li`.

But I think there has to be a better way as I do not seem to get any `if(){}` statements working to process the forms i.e. `if(form1){ $.ajax etc } if (form2) {more ajax}`

Suggestions please - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to load it into the adjacent `div`, so, like this?

```
$('.openuserform').live('click', function(){
    // http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
    $(this).siblings('.userform').load('form-page.php'); 
});
```

This is assuming this markup:

```
<ul>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Info</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Appearence</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Pages</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Services</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
<li><div class="openuserform" >Community</div> <div class="userform"></div></li>
</ul>
```